# mysql join and issues with loading data

Tags: mysql

I am working with mysql code and it is giving me a headache, I will upload my Image of tables how they look like and how i am trying to fetch the data.

> http://pasteboard.co/1kQrvuVn.png

The Issue is:

I am in the Process of Doing an Update/Insert

So with the query I am trying to fetch the common results from both tables and if there is no common stuff, i want to fully load the tasktemplates tables so for values which are new.

Here is the query which i am trying

so the below query runs in a loop for every record and check if the record exists in the temple or task tale or not.

it works but if no task found, it does not load the templates table, so please guide what should i do ..

Thanks

```
select tasktemplates.*,task.* from tasktemplates 
       right join task on task.templateid = tasktemplates.id   
       where 1=1 
       and (templateID = #val(k)# or task.id = #val(k)#)
```

Comment: use left join instead of right join if you want to get rows from tasktemplates if common row does not exist and remove where clause.

Comment: Can you update query becase i want that taskTemplates should always return rows even if there is no matching record in task table

Answer (score 0):

try it-

```
select tasktemplates.*,task.* 
from tasktemplates a 
left join task b 
on b.templateid = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are looking for two different result like which described below:
1. I am trying to fetch the common results from both tables
2. If there is no common stuff, i want to fully load the tasktemplates tables
If my understanding is correct then please use below solution:
Solution for 'I am trying to fetch the common results from both tables' is:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tasktemplates tmp RIGHT JOIN task t ON t.templateid = tmp.id 
WHERE (t.templateID = '1' or t.id = '1');
```

Solution for 'If there is no common stuff, i want to fully load the tasktemplates tables' is:

```
SELECT tmp.*
FROM tasktemplates tmp LEFT JOIN task t on tmp.id = t.templateid
where t.templateID IS NULL;
```

Further, you can use left join for getting all result from `tasktemplates` table. I get an extra record for each unmatched record in the left table `tasktemplates` of the join that every `tasktemplates` gets a mention:

```
SELECT tmpl.*,t.* 
FROM tasktemplates tmpl 
LEFT JOIN task t 
ON t.templateid = tmpl.id;
```

If this is not you are looking for then please provide some more details about your issue.